# sqlite database extracts the data from database but the next time it returns the list with null value

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have kept two categories in navigation item select. Each has two catogeries as income and expense. User has facility to add any catogeries to income. Thus when app starts then the inner categories of income is extracted from database and shown in list view. The same facility is there for expense. 
When the app starts, it works fine at first time and shows data in list view. I can also add categories in it and it is shown in list view fine. But as soon as i go in the expense part from navigation, app crashes and when i checked the logcat error, the expense list is there but the first item is null and remaining are present.

Here is my codes

In custom adapter

```
package com.develop.expense.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Shailendra on 11/30/2016.
 */
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    private TextView itemName;
    private ImageView itemImage;
    public List mlist;
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mlist=objects;

    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater li=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
       View customView=li.inflate(R.layout.customitem,parent,false);
        itemName=(TextView)customView.findViewById(R.id.itemText);
        itemImage=(ImageView)customView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
        Log.v("bababa",mlist.toString());
        itemName.setText(mlist.get(position).toString());


        return customView;
    }
}
```

The fragment of income is

```
public class Income  extends Fragment {
    private ListView listViewIncome;
    private Button button;
    List list= new ArrayList();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_income, container, false);
        listViewIncome=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listViewIncome);
        button=(Button)view.findViewById(R.id.addIncome);
        final MyHandler myhandler= new MyHandler(getActivity());

        List incomeCategoriesList= myhandler.getIncomeCategories();
        incomeCategoriesList.add("Salary");
        incomeCategoriesList.add("Business");
        incomeCategoriesList.add("Bonus");
        incomeCategoriesList.add("Extras");
        Log.v("showme",incomeCategoriesList.toString());
        final CustomAdapter customAdapter=new CustomAdapter(getContext(),R.layout.customitem,incomeCategoriesList);
        listViewIncome.setAdapter(customAdapter);




 button.setOnClickListener(
         new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 AlertDialog.Builder addIncome= new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                 addIncome.setTitle("Add Income Category").setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).setCancelable(true);
                 final EditText incomeInput= new EditText(getContext());
                 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                 incomeInput.setLayoutParams(lp);
                 addIncome.setView(incomeInput);
                 addIncome.setMessage("Enter a new category for income.").setPositiveButton(
                         "Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                             @Override
                             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                 String minput= incomeInput.getText().toString();
                                 myhandler.addCategoryIncome(minput);

                             }
                         }
```

The same kind of class exists for expense.

My database handler is here

```
public class MyHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public ArrayList incomeList= new ArrayList();
    public ArrayList<String> expenseList= new ArrayList<String>();
    public MyHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, ConstantsCatogories.database_name, null, ConstantsCatogories.database_version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(
                "CREATE TABLE "+ ConstantsCatogories.table_name+ "(" + ConstantsCatogories.id_name+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
              ConstantsCatogories.income_name + " TEXT, "+ ConstantsCatogories.expense_name+ " Text);"
        );






    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ ConstantsCatogories.table_name);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    public void addCategoryIncome(String incomeName )
    {
        SQLiteDatabase dba= getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
        cv.put(ConstantsCatogories.income_name,incomeName);
        dba.insert(ConstantsCatogories.table_name,null,cv);
        Log.v("database","added income   "+incomeName);

    }
    public void addCategoryExpense(String expenseName )
    {
        SQLiteDatabase dba=getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues cv= new ContentValues();
        cv.put(ConstantsCatogories.expense_name,expenseName);
        dba.insert(ConstantsCatogories.table_name,null,cv);

    }

    public List<String> getIncomeCategories()
    {

        SQLiteDatabase dba= getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor= dba.query(ConstantsCatogories.table_name, new String[] {ConstantsCatogories.income_name},null,null,null,null,ConstantsCatogories.income_name);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())

            do{
  String tempIncomeCategory=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ConstantsCatogories.income_name));

                incomeList.add(tempIncomeCategory);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        dba.close();
        return incomeList;
    }
    public List<String> getExpenseCategories()
    {

        SQLiteDatabase dba= getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor= dba.query(ConstantsCatogories.table_name, new String[] {ConstantsCatogories.expense_name},null,null,null,null,ConstantsCatogories.expense_name);

        if(cursor.moveToFirst())

            do{
                String tempIncomeCategory=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ConstantsCatogories.expense_name));

                expenseList.add(tempIncomeCategory);
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        dba.close();
        return expenseList;
    }



}
```

whole logcat is here

```
12-01 14:38:24.678 1185-1185/com.develop.fragment_expense.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                          Process: com.develop.fragment_expense.myapplication, PID: 1185
                                                                                          java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                              at com.develop.expense.myapplication.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:36)
                                                                                              at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2929)
                                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1305)
                                                                                              at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1212)
                                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                                              at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:716)
                                                                                              at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:462)
                                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasureChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:668)
                                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:90)
                                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onMeasureChild(AppBarLayout.java:1192)
                                                                                              at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onMeasure(CoordinatorLayout.java:733)
                                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                                              at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
                                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                              at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
                                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1464)
                                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:747)
                                                                                              at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:629)
                                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6328)
                                                                                              at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
                                                                                              at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3158)
                                                                                              at android.view.View.measure(View.java:20158)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2644)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1599)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1891)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1487)
                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7467)
                                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:920)
                                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:695)
                                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
                                                                                              at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:906)
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7224)
                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                            at com.android.inter
```

Comment: it only happens when you add category or every time ? plus add logcat details

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                            Process: com.develop.fragment_expense.myapplication, PID: 12336
                                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
                                                                                                at com.develop.expense.myapplication.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:36)

Comment: this is not the case that that textview is not defined. This is set because the first value of list is always null

Comment: add your whole logcat error details along with your post

Comment: It may be possible there is some null values in database which affects this code and create this situation so you can do one simple and easy way for this as just avoid to add null values from database code where you get entire list

Comment: whats that easy way? at first there is no null value. after i switch from income to expense or vice versa, i get that error

Comment: it unclear ` But as soon as i go in the expense part` how you go , i can't see any code to go somewhere , so just you are adding some items to list and fetch other item from data base and displaying it , explain step by step to produce the error and add relevant code